# Cannot Open Mail using batch (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

My Mail App for Windows 10 starts lagging like CRAZY with 4 second reaction times for each click. (yeah) When that happens I simply have to restart it to fix the issue.  (No one has been able to understand why This happens when mail-app is idle)

I just thought I make a simple batch file who kills the app and restarts it each time I wanna open it so it always opens fresh. (Killing it takes just a second extra)

I managed to find that the name of the mail app process was **HxOutlook.exe** so I wrote this successful code

```
taskkill /IM HxOutlook.exe /F
```

But when trying to boot the process I cannot find out how. I tried the file directly but I get acces denied. Tried running is as my user which is admin, still same error. When trying to run as 'admin' it always says wrong password. However I don't want to have to enter password..

I found the HwOutlook folder and tried Using this code to call .exe:

```
runas /user:Administrator "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_16005.11029.20108.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\HxOutlook.exe"
```

I also created a shortcut from the start menu and it says it executes microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3. But trying to do that gets only error is not recognized as command or program

**What can I add to the batch script to make it open the app again as if I click a shortcut like I can do in start, desktop and taskbar...**

Comment: I'd check the shortcut for what is actually executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just calling the shortcut from the desktop like Mail.lnk solved it for now.

```
taskkill /IM HxOutlook.exe /F
Mail.lnk
```